# fstream end of file question

Tags: c++

I am reading in multiple files. There are roughly 300 of these files. For some reason, if I set the loop to run over 3 iterations, the while loop which is supposed to iterate through each line becomes infinite. My question is: Is there somthing I am forgetting to include in my while loop? For now I am simply trying to read one line at a time, eventually saving some data in the output file. Or is it possible that there is something contained in the data files that is not letting the program reach the end of the file?

```
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;
char outputFilename[] = "output.txt";
int i;

outFile.open(outputFilename, ios::out);

for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    stringstream inputFilename;
    inputFilename << "data/" << i << ".txt";
    inFile.open(inputFilename.str().c_str(), ios::in);
    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "Error opening input files" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    char buffer[256];
    while (!inFile.eof()) {
        cout << "HEY";
        inFile.getline(buffer, 100);
    }
    inFile.close();
}
outFile.close();
```

Update: This works much better

```
char buffer[256];
    while (!inFile.eof()) {
      inFile >> buffer;
    }
```

Comment: Calling `exit` in C++ is a terrible idea.

Comment: What's inside the buffer when it reaches the end of the third file?

Comment: @Mark: Thats what was confusing me. It was just a blank line.

Comment: [Don't use stream.eof().](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4324441)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no sense to check for end-of-file *before* you read. Try this loop contruct instead:

```
    char buffer[256];
    while (inFile.getline(buffer, 100)) {
      cout << "HEY";
    }
```

or, better yet,

```
    std::string buffer;
    while (std::getline(inFile, buffer)) {
      cout << "HEY";
    }
```

EDIT: Fix stoopid bug in string version.

Comment: @VanDang - I have absolutely no idea how your program can enter an infinite loop, nor how this correction could fix it. I suppose there is more to your program than you showing us.

Comment: @Rob: The only thing I left out was which head files were included. And, this code snippet was part of the main function.

Comment: It should be `std::getline(infile, buffer)`.

Comment: When `istream::getline` encounters a line longer than its buffer, it sets the fail bit. Once in that state, `getline` never returns useful data, and never advances the input seek pointer. Thus, eof is never encountered, and `inFile.eof()` never returns true.

Answer (score 2):

Yet again!

Apart from anything else this:

```
while (!inFile.eof()) {
          cout << "HEY";
          inFile.getline(buffer, 100);
```

should be:

```
while ( inFile.getline(buffer, 100) ) {
          cout << "HEY";
```

as a moments thought or a consultation of your documents for eof() will tell you.

Comment: Thank you! It now works perfectly, would you care to explain this?

Comment: @Van It is only sensible to test eof() after a read. It tests if the read failed because of an end-of-file condition. Testing it before  a read is therefore nuts.