# Simple File processing in C++

Tags: c++, file

Trying to read a record of students with their name and numbers. 
Writing to the file seems fine. However, reading from it prints a never-ending output. The statement - while(!file.eof()) - is causing the problem. But it's how I read the remaining person_details. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::fstream;
using std::string;
using std::ios;


class telephone
{
protected:
    string name;
    int number; 
public:
    void getDetails();
    void printDetails() const;
};


void telephone:: getDetails()
{
    cout<<"Enter name : "; getline(cin,name);
    cout<<"Enter number : ";cin>>number;
}

void telephone:: printDetails() const
{
    cout<<"Name : "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Number : "<<number<<endl;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    telephone person;
    fstream file("telefile.txt",ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
    if (!file)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid file name."<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    //writing
    char choice;
    do{
        cout<<"----------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Person : "<<endl;
        cout<<"----------"<<endl;
        person.getDetails();
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&person),sizeof(person));
        cout<<"Enter one more?";    
        cin>>choice;cin.ignore();
    }while(choice == 'y');

    //reading
    file.seekg(0);                    
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&person),sizeof(person));
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        cout<<"----------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Person : "<<endl;
        cout<<"----------"<<endl;
        person.printDetails();
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&person),sizeof(person));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You said `while (!eof())` was causing the problem - *what's* the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't reinterpret a class with a `std::string` member as an array of characters. Do so only for POD types.

Comment: `while (!file.eof())` doesn't *cause* a problem. It *is* a problem.

Comment: [`while (!f.eof())` is ALWAYS wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: @Thomas no, read the link.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: That's actually a really bad link, because all the information there is about <stdio.h> and the `feof` function, which is different from `fstream::eof()`  Some of the same reasoning applies, but none of the code there is even the slightest bit useful here.

Comment: @BenVoigt you're welcome to dig up another link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21647/103167 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5984789/103167  And note that the code in this question IS testing `eof()` *after* attempting a read... still not as good as testing for a good stream via `while (file)`, but not making the naive mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you're making a binary image of a `std::string` object, but a `string` object doesn't contain the character data, only a pointer to it (this is what allows a string to vary in size).  So when you read that pointer back in, you'll start accessing whatever is in that memory location now, not what that memory held when you wrote the file.  oops.  Even worse things will happen when the string destructor runs and tries to free that pointer.

What you should do instead is write `person.name.size()` to the file, followed by that many bytes starting at `&person.name[0]`.  Then when you read in the size, you can `person.name.resize(size_from_file)` and then read that many bytes into `&person.name[0]`.

The Standard actually has a formal name for data types you are allowed to take binary images of: *trivially copyable*. The requirements are set out in section 9 and your `telephone` type doesn't meet them:

> A *trivially copyable* class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-trivial copy constructors,
> - has no non-trivial move constructors,
> - has no non-trivial copy assignment operators,
> - has no non-trivial move assignment operators, and
> - has a trivial destructor.

The compiler-generated special member functions for `telephone` are non-trivial because of the `std::string` member, so instead of meeting all five requirements, you don't meet any of them.

---

Everyone has mentioned `while (!file.eof())`.  You're not actually doing it wrong, but there is room for improvement.

First, you can catch more errors using `while (file.good())` instead.  Right now if you have any failure other than EOF, your loop never terminates, which matches your symptom.

Next, streams have a conversion to bool which is equivalent to calling `good()`, so you can write `while (file)`.  Finally, `read` like most other stream I/O functions returns the original stream, so you can write

```
while (file.read(buffer, size))
```

and avoid duplicating the read call both above and inside the loop.

But you didn't fall into the very common trap of checking `eof()` before doing the read that actually ran into the end.  Bravo for that.