# C++ read from file returning extra lines

Tags: c++, linked-list, ifstream, getline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Testing stream.good() or !stream.eof() reads last line twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324441/testing-stream-good-or-stream-eof-reads-last-line-twice)

I'm working on an assignment where I am required to read data from a file into a linked list. So far I am able to read the file into the linked list with no problem, however everytime i read from the file into the list, i get one extra entry:

here's my struct:

```
struct Video { 
char video_name[1024];      // video name
int ranking;                // Number of viewer hits
char url[1024];             // video URL
YouTubeVideo *next;  // pointer to Video structure
}  *head = NULL;        // EMPTY linked list
```

here's my read-in code:

```
void load()
{
ifstream rankFile ("Ranking.dbm");
struct Video *temp;
if (rankFile.is_open())
{
    string line;
    do {

        temp = (Video*)malloc(sizeof(Video)); //allocate space for node 
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        rankFile.getline(temp->video_name,1024);
        rankFile >> temp->ranking;
        getline(rankFile, line); // need to skip 'ranking's
        // unread new-line
        rankFile.getline(temp->url,1024);


    }while (rankFile.good() );

    rankFile.close();
}

else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

return ;

}
```

it is reading from a file that looks like this:

```
spiderman
100
spiderman.com
lucy
30
lucy.com
disney
1200
disney.com
```

these all read in fine, however it appears that the `do-while(rankFile.good());` loop goes through one more iteration giving me an empty node in the linked list. I have already tried using all of my `getline()` statements as conditions of the while loop and that didnt seem to change anything. Also using `rankFile != eof` gave me no luck.

Is there a way to be checking the next I/O to make sure its not `\n` or the end of file?

Comment: Any reason to not start with `while(rankFile.good())`? You want the empty file to be correctly read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to `while(rankFile.good())` instead of using the `do...while` syntax. `do...while` doesn't evaluate the terminating condition on your last iteration until after the contents of the loop have finished processing. A simple `while` will evaluate before processing the loop body.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that i had tried this before.... and it still is giving me an empty node.

Comment: You can check the stream using the peek() function. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/peek/

Comment: awesome peek() did the trick! thanks

Comment: np, good luck on your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Do-while loop executes first and checks the condition afterwards. So one step more always as first time, the loop would always run. 
While loop checks condition first before executing the body. So no extra iteration.

Check it here.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/