# "String subscript out of range" error using vectors

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am trying to pull characters from a specific column (in this case, 0) of a text file, and load them into a vector. The code seems to work ok, until it reaches the end, when I get a "string subscript out of range" error, and I do not know how to fix this. Does anyone know what I can do? Here is the relevant code.

```
class DTree
{
private:

    fstream newList;
    vector<string> classes;
public:
     DTree();
    ~DTree();

void loadAttributes();
};

void DTree::loadAttributes()
{ 

string line = "";
newList.open("newList.txt");
string attribute = "";
while(newList.good())
{
    getline(newList, line);

    attribute = line[0];
    classes.push_back(attribute);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `line` was read ok? If so, how are you sure?

Comment: `line` must be empty(size() == 0), does your file start with a blank line? [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) reads until the first '\n' or new line character

Comment: @KarthikT, You mean a blank line, but same idea.

Comment: I agree with chris, you should check line.size() > index before accessing line[index].

Comment: And along with that, you should check the input operation to ensure it succeeded. Don't forget checking to make sure the file opened as well.

Comment: @chris Yes, I am sure that it is read ok. I can see it when I put a break point in the while loop. It successfully gets each line, from what I can see. (I didn't check all 5000+, but I assume it's the same?)

Comment: It's possible that the final line is read in correctly, in which case `ios::good()` will return true (causing the code to re-enter the loop), but a subsequent read (`getline`) after that will have `line` be an empty string.

Comment: @chris The file opens correctly, and it does load characters into the vector (at first).

Comment: just try while(getline(newList, line) instead of checking for 'good'

Comment: @Chubsdad I didn't realize you could do that. That appears to have fixed it! Thank you very much :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try `'while(getline(newList, line)'`

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324441/testing-stream-good-or-stream-eof-reads-last-line-twice)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like

```
ifstream ifs("filename",ios::in);

string temp;
getline(ifs,temp)// Called as prime read

while(ifs)
{
    //Do the operations
    // ....

    temp.clear();
    getline(ifs,temp);
}
ifs.clear();
ifs.close();
```

This works for almost all kinds of files.You can replace `getline(ifs,temp)` by `get()` function or by `>>` operator based on your requirements.