# How do I open a .txt file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile("hey.txt");

  myfile >> line;
  cout << line;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Why does this not print out what is in my "hey.txt" file?

Comment: You have to check the state of `myfile`. For example, if it found the file `hey.txt` to open.

Comment: And whether the read succeeded.

Answer (score 7):

This should do the job, If you are new to these things please read http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

> EDIT: in article above .good() is a bad practice, look here if you need to more detail [Testing stream.good() or !stream.eof() reads last line twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324441/testing-stream-good-or-stream-eof-reads-last-line-twice)

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {

    while(getline(myfile, line)) {
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You copy-and-pasted some bad example code. That `while (myfile.good())` loop is a [bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324441/testing-stream-good-or-stream-eof-reads-last-line-twice).

Comment: @Blastfurnace I agree, I'll add the link

Comment: Instead of `else cout << "Unable to open file";`, is there a way to throw a FileNotFoundException? I'm newbie in C++.