# c++ vector array error

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

```
int main()
{
    int n, inInt;
    vector <int> list;
    ifstream ifs("1.txt");
    float a;
    ifs >> a;
    std::vector<int> result;
    int temp;

    while(! ifs.eof())
    {
        ifs >> temp;
        result.push_back(temp);
    }

    int b;
    b = result.size();
    float array[b+1];
    int i;
    array[0] = a;

    for(i = 1;i < b+1;i++) {
        array[i] = (array[i-1] + result[i]-2*array[i-1] * result[i]/a); 
    }
    cout << array[b];

    system("pause");
    return 0;}
```

Basically in my code, I built a vector and build an array and try to use the data from the vector in the array.However,when I text the code,it gave me a huge incorrect number.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to make existing answers wrong. If the answers solve the initial problem but you then encounter a new problem that you can't solve please post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

`temp` is not an array, `temp` is an int. You're trying to use `operator[]` on an int you cannot do that. Also, VLAs (Variable Length Arrays) are a GCC extension, and therefore not standard. I suggest you replace this line:

```
float array[b+1];
```

With:

```
std::vector<float> array(b+1);
```

Comment: sorry I am not quite familiar with vector.Then                   array[i] = (array[i-1] + result[i]-2*array[i-1] * result[i]/a);           how can i edit this part?

Comment: You don't need to. Vectors act just like array, the difference is they can change in size and manage their own memory (amongst other things). Operator [] works on vectors just like it does on arrays.

Comment: std::vector<float> array(b+1)...?is this an array or a vector...?

Comment: `std::vector<float> array(b+1);` is a variable of name array, of type vector (that holds floats) which contains b+1 elements.

Comment: The input is 3 2 2 ,suppose to get 1.66666667,but evertime still get a random huge number.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two problems. First, [your input loop is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324441/testing-stream-good-or-stream-eof-reads-last-line-twice) and inserts an invalid entry into `result`. You can fix this by using the following input loop:

```
while (ifs >> temp)
{
    result.push_back(temp);
}
```

Second, the vector `result` contains `b` elements so the valid indices are `[0..b-1]`. Your loop end condition `i < b+1` will read one element past the end of `result`. I think you can fix this issue by doing this instead:

```
for(i = 0; i < b; i++)
{
    array[i+1] = (array[i] + result[i]-2*array[i] * result[i]/a);
}
```

When I made these changes and used `3 2 2` for input, the output was `1.66667`