# Trying to print from an input file but printing the last input twice

Tags: c++, file-io

Im trying to print from an input file, which at the time has only one set of entries but when I try to print it, it shows it twice and I cant figure out why.  Any help would be appreciated.  Heres the code

```
ifstream orders;    
int idNum = 0;
int quantity = 0;
double totalCost = 0;

orders.open("processedOrders.dat");
if (orders.is_open())
{
cout << "Order Number" << setw(16) << "Quantity" << setw(22) << "Total Cost" << endl;
    while (!orders.eof())
    {
        orders >> idNum >> quantity >> totalCost;
        cout << "  " << idNum << setw(18) << quantity << setw(23) << totalCost << endl;
    }
        orders.close();
}
```

Comment: Did you search this on StackOverflow ?

Comment: `while (!orders.eof())` doesn't do what you think

Comment: I believe that this will shed light on your problem ->  http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Files/End.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing stream.good() or !stream.eof() reads last line twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324441/testing-stream-good-or-stream-eof-reads-last-line-twice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EOF mark not read yet, which calls for the next iteration, hence last line twice.

Check for EOF inside the loop, like this :-

```
if (orders.is_open())
{
cout << "Order Number" << setw(16) << "Quantity" << setw(22) << "Total Cost" << endl;
    while (true)
    {
        orders >> idNum >> quantity >> totalCost;
        if( orders.eof() ) break;
        cout << "  " << idNum << setw(18) << quantity << setw(23) << totalCost << endl;
    }
        orders.close();
}
```

Following should also achieve the expected result:

```
if (orders.is_open())
 while (orders >> idNum >> quantity >> totalCost) 
   cout << "  " << idNum << setw(18) << quantity << setw(23) << totalCost << endl;
```