# Last element added to an array is being added twice, unable to figure out why

Tags: c++, arrays, insertion-sort

Realization: Wow spent so much time staring at this code I finally noticed something I'd been missing all along. I initialize i = size which means at the start the array is looking at an unfilled spot so I finally understand why it always puts a repeat. Now to attempt to fix it. Feel free to berate me.

I'm looking through the array backwards because I'm using an insertion sort algorithm so I work backwards from the last known element to alphabetize the data. However no matter what the final line in the data file (from which I'm reading) it always repeats twice. Here is the array contents printed to demonstrate the repeat:

```
List of names sorted:
 100 bill gates
 100 bill gates
 65 duck donald
 60 frog freddie
 71 ghost casper
 85 mouse abby
 73 mouse mickey
 95 mouse minnie
```

Notice that bill gates is listed twice. The problem appears to be with the way I'm looping. If I modify the lower bound in the loop to 1 instead of 0 then shit goes haywire. Here is the function in question, I don't believe any of the code outside is relevant so I did not include it:

```
bool sortInput(ifstream &infile, StudentType students[], int &size)
{
   StudentType temp;

   //empty condition
   if(size == 0)
   {
      infile >> temp.last >> temp.first >> temp.grade;
      strcpy(students[0].last, temp.last);
      strcpy(students[0].first, temp.first);
      students[0].grade = temp.grade;
      size++;
   } 

   while(infile)
   {
      infile >> temp.last >> temp.first >> temp.grade;

      if(temp.grade >= LOWGRADE && temp.grade <= MAXGRADE)
      {            
         for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
         {       
            if(strcmp(temp.last, students[i-1].last) < 0)
            {
               students[i] = students[i-1];
               students[i-1] = temp;
            }
            else if(strcmp(temp.last, students[i-1].last) == 0 && strcmp(temp.first, students[i-1].first) < 0)
            {
               students[i] = students[i-1];
               students[i-1] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
               students[i] = temp;
               break;
            }
         }

         size++;

         //tester loop to print contents every step of the way
         for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {
            cout << "TEST: " << students[i].last << " " << students[i].first << " " << students[i].grade << endl;
         }
         cout << "DONE" << endl;

      } //end for loop  
   } //end while loop

   return true;
}
```

However if the full code is necessary for further context then here it is:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// You write meaningful doxygen comments and assumptions

#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int const MAXSIZE = 100;            // maximum number of records in total
int const MAXLENGTH = 31;           // maximum string length 
int const MAXGRADE = 100;           // highest possible grade
int const LOWGRADE = 0;             // lowest possible grade
int const GROUP = 10;               // group amount
int const HISTOGRAMSIZE = (MAXGRADE-LOWGRADE)/GROUP + 1;    // grouped by GROUP

struct StudentType  {               // information of one student
   int grade;                       // the grade of the student
   char last[MAXLENGTH];            // last name (MAXLENGTH-1 at most)
   char first[MAXLENGTH];           // first name (MAXLENGTH-1 at most)
};

// prototypes go here
bool sortInput(ifstream &, StudentType [], int &);
void displayList(StudentType [], int);
void setHistogram(int [], StudentType [], int);
void displayHistogram(int []);
int findAverage(StudentType [], int);

//------------------------------- main ----------------------------------------
int main()  {
   StudentType students[MAXSIZE];   // list of MAXSIZE number of students
   int size = 0;                    // total number of students
   int histogram[HISTOGRAMSIZE];    // grades grouped by GROUP
   int average = 0;                 // average exam score, truncated

   // creates file object and opens the data file
   ifstream infile("data1.txt");
   if (!infile)  { 
      cout << "File could not be opened." << endl; 
      return 1;  
   }

   // read and sort input by last then first name
   bool successfulRead = sortInput(infile, students, size);              

   // display list, histogram, and class average 
   if (successfulRead)  {
      displayList(students, size);
      setHistogram(histogram, students, size);
      displayHistogram(histogram);
      average = findAverage(students, size);
      cout << "Average grade: " << average << endl << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}

bool sortInput(ifstream &infile, StudentType students[], int &size)
{
   StudentType temp;

   //empty condition
   if(size == 0)
   {
      infile >> temp.last >> temp.first >> temp.grade;
      strcpy(students[0].last, temp.last);
      strcpy(students[0].first, temp.first);
      students[0].grade = temp.grade;
      size++;
   } 

   while(infile)
   {
      infile >> temp.last >> temp.first >> temp.grade;

      if(temp.grade >= LOWGRADE && temp.grade <= MAXGRADE)
      {            
         for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
         {       
            if(strcmp(temp.last, students[i-1].last) < 0)
            {
               students[i] = students[i-1];
               students[i-1] = temp;
            }
            else if(strcmp(temp.last, students[i-1].last) == 0 && strcmp(temp.first, students[i-1].first) < 0)
            {
               students[i] = students[i-1];
               students[i-1] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
               students[i] = temp;
               break;
            }
         }

         size++;

         for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {
            cout << "TEST: " << students[i].last << " " << students[i].first << " " << students[i].grade << endl;
         }
         cout << "DONE" << endl;

      } //end for loop  
   } //end while loop

   return true;
}

void displayList(StudentType students[], int size)
{
   cout << "List of names sorted:" << endl;

   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      cout << " " << students[i].grade << " " << students[i].last << " " << students[i].first << endl;
   }

   cout << endl;
}

void setHistogram(int histogram[], StudentType students[], int size)
{
   int groupIndex;

   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      groupIndex = (students[i].grade - LOWGRADE) / GROUP;
      histogram[groupIndex]++;
   }
}

void displayHistogram(int histogram[])
{
   cout << "Histogram of grades: " << endl;
   int bottomBin = LOWGRADE;
   int binWidth = (MAXGRADE - LOWGRADE) / GROUP - 1;
   int topBin = bottomBin + binWidth;

   for(int i = 0; i < HISTOGRAMSIZE; i++)
   {
      cout << bottomBin << "--> " << topBin << ": ";

      for(int j = 0; j < histogram[i]; j++)
      {
         cout << "*";
      }

      cout << endl;
      bottomBin += binWidth + 1;
      topBin = min(topBin + binWidth + 1, MAXGRADE);
   }
}

int findAverage(StudentType students[], int size)
{
   int total = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      total += students[i].grade;
   }

   return total / size;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// functions with meaningful doxygen comments and assumptions go here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the stream extraction and testing the stream state by changing:

```
while(infile)
{
    infile >> temp.last >> temp.first >> temp.grade;
    ...
}
```

to

```
while(infile >> temp.last >> temp.first >> temp.grade)
{
   ...
}
```

This will read the stream and fail (return false) if the read fails for any reason, including EOF.

Note: read [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324441/testing-stream-good-or-stream-eof-reads-last-line-twice) for more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

End-of-file indicator is set not when the last byte of file is read, but when an attempt is made to read the next byte, the byte that doesn't exist.

Thus, after the last line is read, `while(infile)` check still succeeds, but `infile >> temp.last` call fails, leaving the variable intact. You don't check for that failure, so you run one extra iteration of the loop, using values read by the previous iteration.

Comment: Yes. You first attempt to read, and then check whether the read succeeded. You can't check beforehand whether the future read will succeed, which is basically what your current code is trying to do.

Comment: Deleted the previous comment because I fudged it up... hehe. How would I properly check for that call to succeed? If I use 'ifstream.good()' as a condition on that if statement then it simply omits the last element entirely instead of repeating it. Same thing happens if I use '!ifstream.eof()'

Comment: I don't see how your code could ever work. Each line of the file is of the form "int string string", but you are reading a string, a string and an int.