# Having a SegFault where there should be none

Tags: c++

Program keeps throwing a seg fault under conditions where it should not. I have arrays and vectors, and have tried both options. Seems to always throw the seg fault on the third value of the array/vector of 3. There is another functions after this that when commented out lets it go a few more times. But the results is the same, it still seg faults.

```
    char bits[3];//vector<char> bits(3,'0');
    vector<string> inputs;
    string temp;
    for(int x = 0;!i.eof();x++)
    {
            getline(i, temp);
            inputs.push_back(temp);
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < inputs.size();x++)
    {
       cout << endl << inputs[x];
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < 3;x++)
    {
       cout << endl << bits[x];
    }
    for(int cursor = 0;cursor< inputs.size();cursor++)
    {
    cout << endl << "bitstogoin " << cursor;
    cout << endl << inputs.size();
            bits[0]=inputs[cursor][0];
    cout << endl << "got1 " << bits[0];
            bits[1]=inputs[cursor][1];
    cout << endl << "got2 " << bits[1];
            bits[2]=inputs[cursor][2];  //seg faults on this line.
    cout << endl << "bitsin";
    for(int t = 0; t < 3;t++)
    {
    cout << bits[t];
   }
```

The commands that are being given via the input file look like:
    100 10110101
    101 11001011
    111
    110
    000
    111
    110 etc...

Comment: How are you guaranteeing that each string in inputs has at least a length of 3? If you read in a string of length 2, then `inputs[cursor][2]` will go out of bounds.

Comment: The command codes i am reading in are a set of three binary bits, thus the title. It essentially goes into a 3x8 decoder after that. input looks like:
100
110
101
111 1101001
101 1001001
etc.

Comment: Story of my life, (and many others).

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this probably has nothing to do with your segfault but should still be addressed.*

The following input loop has two problems. First, the `x` is pointless because you never do anything with the value of `x`. Second, looping on `eof()` is rarely correct (see: [Testing stream.good() or !stream.eof() reads last line twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324441/testing-stream-good-or-stream-eof-reads-last-line-twice)).

```
for(int x = 0;!i.eof();x++)
{
    getline(i, temp);
    inputs.push_back(temp);
}
```

Try the following instead:

```
while (getline(i, temp))
{
    inputs.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: That is something I hadn't thought of. The for look I suppose was just habit as this particular program has about 15 more for loops. Guess I got stuck in a loop writing loop myself.

Answer (score 0):

In your code here:

```
 vector<string> inputs;
    string temp;
    for(int x = 0;!i.eof();x++)
    {
            getline(i, temp);
            inputs.push_back(temp);
    }
```

You read in strings and place them into a vector.

Ask yourself this? What is the length of each of these strings?

When you call

```
bits[2]=inputs[cursor][2];
```

You are accessing the 3rd character of a string in that vector. Before this statement try this:

```
if (inputs[cursor].size() < 3)
   cout << "String is less than 3!" << endl;
```

If your program prints that debug line, then you know you're in trouble.

Indeed, you're not really doing anything to check the lengths of your strings before you try to access characters in them.

Comment: I plugged that bit into the code before it runs the placing of the bits, and it did not give that print before it seg faulted.

Comment: @user2981171 Do you have a debugger? Can you place a breakpoint before the point of segfault and make sure all your data is good?

Comment: I tried using Visual Studio, but for some reason, I always have problems running code that accepts files through visual studio. It has a habit is breaking before I can even get to the meat of a program.

Comment: @Serathano: If that is the case, I suggest a few things: print out the sizes of all strings before you try to set bits, which could be unwieldy if you have a large number, OR, modify your input to read from the terminal, and then change it to read from a file when you have verified it works. Finally, you can always try to get some help (online or from a friend) in getting your debugger to work. I really feel like you're having a bad-data issue.