# why does char[1] read entire word from my input file?

Tags: c++, arrays, file

this is what I have done till now: I want to read words from file in C++ and I am allowed to use only cstring library. this is my piece of code

```
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream file;
    char word[1];


    file.open("p.txt");



    while (!file.eof()){

        file >> word;
        cout << word << endl;

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It is working fine and reading one word at a time. But I don't understand how this is working fine.
How can char array of any size be it char word[1] or char word[50] read only one word at a time ignoring spaces.

And further I want to store these words in dynamic array. How can I achieve this? Any guidance would be appreciated?

Comment: See ["while( !feof( file ) )" is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941)

Comment: Probably because the type of a C-string is `char *` and the type of an array of characters is `char *`.  In one method or another, the array is decomposing to `char *`.

Comment: This is a buffer overflow. Use `std::string`.

Comment: Its *not* "working fine". Don't confuse *observed* behavior with *defined* behavior. Send it through Valgrind.

Comment: I suggest you use `std::string` to avoid problems like this.  For a single characters, don't use an array.

Comment: the only explanation is that you are getting lucky. For strings longer than a character, `file >> word` is going to write over memory it hasn't allocated, which is UB. Why aren't you using `std::string`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi)

Comment: @RedAlert, not 'for strings longer than a character' but, actually, for *any* string. Remember that C/C++ string are NUL-terminated, one-char array can contain only an empty string, one-char string needs 2-char array.

Comment: Sorry, selected the wrong dupe link, this one I meant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 7):

Your code has undefined behaviour. `operator >>` simply overwrites memory beyond the array.

Take into account that included by you header `<stdio.h>` is not used in the program. On the other hand you need to include header `<cstdlib>` that declares function `system`.

As for your second question then you should use for example standard container `std::vector<std::string>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("p.txt");
    std::string s;
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.reserve( 100 );



    while ( file >> s ) v.push_back( s );

    std::system( "pause" );

    return 0;
}
```

Or you can simply define the vector as

```
std::vector<std::string> v( ( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( file ) ),
                            std::istream_iterator<std::string>() );
```

provided that you will include header `<iterator>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("p.txt");
    std::vector<std::string> v( ( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( file ) ),
                                std::istream_iterator<std::string>() );

    for ( const std::string &s : v ) std::cout << s << std::endl;

    std::system( "pause" );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is invoking undefined behavior. That it doesn't crash is a roll of the dice, but its execution is not deterministic precisely because that is the nature of being *undefined*.

The easiest way (I've found) to load a file of words with whitespace separation is by:

```
std::ifstream inp("p.txt");
std::istream_iterator<std::string> inp_it(inp), inp_eof;
std::vector<std::string> strs(inp_it, inp_eof);
```

`strs` will contain every whitespace delimited char sequence as a linear vector of `std::string`. Use `std::string` for dynamic string content and don't feel the least bit guilty about exploiting the hell out of the hard work those that came before you gave us all: [The Standard Library](http://www.cppreference.com).

Answer (score 1):

You're using C++, so you can avoid all that C stuff.

```
std::string word;
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::fstream stream("wordlist");

// this assumes one word (or phrase, with spaces, etc) per line...
while (std::getline(stream, word))    
    words.push_back(word);
```

or for multiple words (or phrases, with spaces, etc) per line separated by commas:

```
while (std::getline(stream, word, ','))    
    words.push_back(word);
```

or for multiple words per line separated by spaces:

```
while(stream >> word)
    words.push_back(word);
```

No need to worry about buffer sizes or memory allocation or anything like that.

Comment: checking if the stream is good is a bad programming practise.

Comment: This code is broken, see: [Testing stream.good() or !stream.eof() reads last line twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324441/testing-stream-good-or-stream-eof-reads-last-line-twice)

Comment: @Veritas: you are of course entirely correct. Mea culpa. Fixed now, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

It works because you are lucky and you don't overwrite some critical memory. You need to allocate enough bytes for `char word` array, say `char word[64]`. And use `while(file>>word)` as your test for `EOF`. In the loop you can `push_back` the word into a `std::vector<string>` if you are allowed to use `C++` STL.

If you want a simple C++11  STL-like solution, use this

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ifstream fin("./in.txt"); // input file
   vector<string> words; // store the words in a vector 
   copy(istream_iterator<string>(fin),{}, back_inserter(words)); // insert the words
   for(auto &elem: words)
       cout << elem << endl; // display them
}
```

Or, more compactly, construct the container directly from the stream iterator like

```
vector<string> words(istream_iterator<string>(fin),{});
```

and remove the `copy` statement.

If instead a `vector<string>` you use a `multiset<string>` (`#include <set>`) and change

```
copy(istream_iterator<string>(fin),{}, back_inserter(words)); // insert the words
```

to

```
copy(istream_iterator<string>(fin),{}, inserter(words, words.begin())); // insert the words
```

you get the words ordered. So using STL is the cleanest approach in my opinion.

Comment: There are words in the english language with more than 40 letters (there are others but here is an example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis ).  If you include hyphens it can get much longer than that.  There is no way to be sure that char[X] is a big enough array - you need something that will grow automatically like a std::string.

Comment: Sure, I just pointed out that `char word[1]` is not enough (edited my answer now). In any case, one should use STL and not plain old C in C++, it makes no sense to use a language like C++ in C-style mode, unless you get a significant performance decrease (which is not the case for STL).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing due to the overload of `char *` for `operator>>`.

An array of `char`, regardless the size, will decompose to the type `char *` where the value is the address of the start of the array.

For compatibility with the C language, the overloaded `operator>>(char *)` has been implemented to read one or more characters until a terminating *whitespace* character is reached, or there is an error with the stream.

If you declare an array of 1 character and read from a file containing "California", the function will put 'C' into the first location of the array **and** keep writing the remaining characters to the next locations in memory (regardless of what data type they are).  This is known as a *buffer overflow*.

A much safer method is to read into a `std::string` or if you only want one character, use a `char` variable.  Look in your favorite C++ reference for the `getline` methods.  There is an overload for reading until a given delimiter is reached.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this was helpful for me. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a couple changes:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
int main(){

    ifstream file;
    string word;    

    file.open("p.txt");    

    while (file >> word){
        cout << word << endl;    
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file>>char *
```

Will work with any char * and you are using

```
file >> word;
```

and it simply sees work variable as a char * but you are getting a segemntation fault somewhere and if your code grows you will see something is not working without any logical reason. GDB debugger will show you the seg fault