# std::stof works on Visual Studio 2019 (Windows) but not XCode

Tags: c++, xcode

I have the following code that works fine on my Windows machine, but not when I'm developing at home on my (M1) Mac. It is for parsing a line in a csv file into floats...

```cpp
std::stringstream ss("1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0"); // Example line.
std::vector<float> storedValues;

while(ss.good())
{
    std::string substring;
    std::getline(ss, substring, ',');

    float entry = std::stof(substring); // This is where it breaks.
    storedValues.push_back(entry);
}
```

On Windows (Visual Studio 2019) this will compile. On my machine I get the following complaint:

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stof: no conversion
terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stof: no conversion
```

What is even more strange is that the following WILL work on my XCode setup, no problem:

```cpp
float test = std::stof("0.1");
```

So I don't know. What do you think?

Comment: That's not a compilation error. It's a runtime error.

Comment: What compiler (and version) are you using?

Comment: @ChrisMM I'm using XCode Version 13.3.1, 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3)

Comment: Don't use `while(ss.good())`, it is causing the last string to be empty. Move the `substring` declaration up, out of the loop, and use `while(std::getline(ss, substring, ','))` instead. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4324441/1458097

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be because you are attempting to convert `""` (empty string) to float.

As you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Gnxs4xd4s), VS terminates prior to printing the float and returns an exit code, while g++ and clang throw.

As mentioned in the comments, using `ss.good()` as the loop condition is actually a problem. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324441/testing-stream-good-or-stream-eof-reads-last-line-twice) for more information. Essentially though, the last time through the loop, your string `substring` ends up being empty. Thus, when passed to `stof`, it should throw.

`stof` should throw an `std::invalid_argument` if no conversion can be performed (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)); which is what should happen for empty strings.

Comment: No, MSVC does not allow empty string conversion to float. Your example code on Godbolt shows that the program exited with error code `3221226505` (or `0xC0000409` in hex), which is [`STATUS_FAIL_FAST_EXCEPTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/inside/c0000409). Basically, due to uncaught C++ exception. See [another example](https://godbolt.org/z/cKxccd5je), which shows it is an `std::invalid_argument` exception (with "invalid stof argument" in its explanatory text).

Comment: @heapunderrun, you're right, I didn't pay much attention to the output when running and just saw that it wasn't the same exception that was printed like the other two.